# Safely coalesce on JavaScript sub property

Tags: javascript, undefined, coalesce

I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do both null coalescing and checking for undefined?

For example, I have a variable that I want to initialize to a property value of an object that may or may not be defined, in that event null is best because falseyness is a wonderful thing

```
function DoWork(){
    var foobar = 
      typeof foo !== "undefined" 
        ? typeof foo["bar"] !== "undefined" 
          ? foo["bar"] || null 
          : null 
        : null;

    ...
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(foobar));   //output is either foo["bar"]'s value or null
```

As you can see this gets messy.  I'm curious if there's a better way to handle this kind of thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in syntax for this. Libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) have deep-get methods, that solve this problem:

```
_.get(x, 'deep.path.property')
```

The above will return the value of `x.deep.path.property`, or `undefined` if *any* of the objects along the way, including `x`, do not exist.

Such a function is not hard to write. You can do so as a thinking exercise, and get the interface you want (with `null` instead of `undefined`), or you can look up the [`lodash.get`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/get.js) implementation (you'll need to follow some imports).

Answer (score 4):

Optional chaining was introduced in ES2020 and it can be used with the nullish coalescing operator.

```js
const myNestedProp = user?.profile?.name?.last_name ?? null;

// It will print the value of the nested prop `last_name`
// or null if it's undefined
console.log(myNestedProp);
```

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining